# Installing postman on centOS fails due to error postman: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6)

Tags: gcc, libc

I want to install Postman on my centOS 6.9. 
I have 4.8.2 gcc version installed at 
$ which gcc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc

While running Postman app I'm getting below err

```
$ postman
postman: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6)
postman: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6)
postman: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6)
```

Have gone through related stackoverflow questions but couldn't fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This CentOS installation is corrupted.  Someone seems to have copied `libstdc++.so.6` from another distribution (perhaps CentOS 7).  It is probably best to throw away this installation and start over from scratch (maybe this time with CentOS 7).

Comment: How can you say that for sure ? This distribution of centOS is provided by employer.

Comment: You can run `rpm -Va` to get a list of files shipped in RPM packages which have been modified after installation (outside of RPM), and you should also check that `rpm -qi libstdc++` outputs the expected package version for CentOS 6.